# Почему картинку в unity размазывает

Tags: unity3d, изображения, png, unity3d-ui

Есть пиксельная картинка:

[image: Dice]

Почему, когда я ее вставляю в unity получается такой эффект:

[image: Dice]

Настройки картинки (файла):

[image: Настройки файла]

Настройки картинки (как объект в unity)

[image: Настройки объекта]

Также на UI включен pixel perfect

Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Comment: Разве качество картинки не улучшилось?

Comment: Качество наоборот ухудшилось (к примеру обводка была в 1 пискель, а в игре совсем подругому)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это зависит от параметра Format в самом низу настроек файла. Попробуй поиграться с ним и ставить разные значения, должно помочь.